# Unable to use query.Or() and other functions in google cloud datastore sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk

I was going thru the google cloud datastore [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-basic-query-python). When I came across this code snippet

```
query_filter = query.Or(
    [
        query.PropertyFilter("starred", "=", True),
        query.And([query.PropertyFilter("done", "=", False),
                    query.PropertyFilter("priority", "=", 4,),
        ]
        )   
    ]
)
```

This would be incredibly useful in my current project. However when I tried using it I got the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'Or'
```

At first, I assumed it was due to me having an outdated version, so I updated with pip. below is an excerpt from my requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-datastore>=2.15.1
google-cloud-storage>=2.8.0
```

No cigar, so I tried updating my sdk with `gcloud components update`

But it still doesn't let me use query.Or(). Nor does it let me use other features like `IN` in `query.add_filter('id', 'IN', 'id_list')`

I've tried, but I can't figure out what's wrong. All the other functions work as expected.

Here's the code where I get the error. Am I calling on the wrong object?

```
query = datastore_client.query()
query.Or()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/queries#class-googleclouddatastorequeryorfilters), your code should use `datastore.query` i.e.

```
query_filter = datastore.query.Or(
    [
        datastore.query.PropertyFilter("starred", "=", True),
        datastore.query.And([datastore.query.PropertyFilter("done", "=", False),
                    datastore.query.PropertyFilter("priority", "=", 4,),
        ]
        )   
    ]
)
```

If you want to use the code as written in the documentation you referenced, then you have to first do

`from google.cloud.datastore import query`

Comment: oy vey, I was tried from google.cloud import datastore query and was getting an error. Thanks for the help